# Error importing excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to var_dump data from an excel sheet but it is taking longer than normal. In fact, the server times. I am using maatwebsite/excel to import this excel file. How do I resolve this.

This is what I am doing:

```
 $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
 $data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {})->get();
 dd($data);
```

I am using Laravel 5.5 and Maatwebsite 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $path = Input::file('file_import')->getRealPath();
    $inserts = [];
    Excel::load($path,function($reader) use (&$inserts)
    Excel::load($path,function($reader) use (&$inserts)
    {
    foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows){
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $inserts[] = ['email' => $row['email'], 'username' => $row
            ['username'], 'password' => $row['password'], 'first_name' => $row['first_name'],'middle_name' => $row['middle_name], 'last_name' => $row['last_name]];
        }
    }
```

Try this example bro just change the field that you need.